# Cooking fruits with hot sauces

Tags: sauce

i use canned peaches, pears and pinneapple in some of my sauces. I usually cook the fruit with the sauce. Would there be a difference in flavor if I was to cook the sauce then blend the fruit at the end instead of cooking it. Guess I'm wondering if the fruit flavors would have a more fresh and apparent flavor in the sauce.

Comment: Don't you have to cook the fruit at some point to kill all the bad stuff?

Comment: @Catija what do you refer to with "bad stuff"?

Comment: @Ron the reason you cook stuff when you can it is to kill the bacteria that could otherwise grow and kill you. Some mixtures can get around this by being sufficiently inhospitable to bacterial growth but it's still not necessarily a great idea to leave fruit un-heated. I don't know all of the rules, though... and the OP hasn't explained what all goes in the sauce, so there's no way to know if it's safe to add fruit without cooking it properly.

Comment: Consider dried fruit, they also won't water down the sauce ... and they can bring intense aromas and texture...

Comment: Never thought of that, thanks. Be giving that a try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are 1) cooking the fruit a fair amount of time and/or 2) using not-too-little amount of fruit compared to sauce, there will , almost definitely, be difference in flavor, and yes, it should have more "fresh" notes, and it will also miss some of the cooked-fruit notes. If you are after fresh notes, may I suggest using frozen, or even fresh fruits?

Comment: I'm looking for the fruit to balance some of the acid from the vinegar, tomato and lime juice without making it a "fruity sauce" which seems to help. So do u think cooking the fruit less will end up giving it that fruity flavor vs cooking it for 20 or so minutes?

Comment: I do like the idea of fresh fruit and frozen fruit might be a good alternative to canned.

Comment: I think it should help in upping the fruity notes, yes.